# No bitcoins in my multibit wallet, but I have some when I look in the blockchain

Tags: multibit, multibit-hd

I got an old version of multibit (the one like in my picture)

[image]

It says I don't have any funds even when I reset my wallet (multiple times which takes about half an hour each time).

When I look at blockchain.info and search my wallet address it says I still have some bitcoin left.

[image]

I got a wallet.dat file somewhere but I don't know how to import it into the new multibit (multibit HD) since they require you to have some mnemonic or something. There is no simple open wallet button like in the old multibit.

What can I do?

Answer (score -1):

I just deleted my original answer now because I realised it was wrong.

If you have a wallet.dat file, then multibit classic is not the Bitcoin wallet you would have used. Chances are, you used the original Bitcoin software.

First you will need Python 2.7:
64 bit version
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7/python-2.7.amd64.msi

Download this private key extraction utility which will display the private keys for your wallet.dat

https://github.com/dlitz/pywallet

Download the zip and unzip.

Open the command line (windows key + r) type cmd then press enter. Change directory to the folder you downloaded ie:

cd c:\Downloads\pywallet-master

Or c:\users\mike\downloads\pywallet-master

then type:

python pywallet.py --dumpwallet

press enter and you should hopefully see a list of bitcoin addresses and private keys (which start with the number 5).

Once you have these private keys, open a wallet with blockchain.info

and once you're in, click on the Import/Export button and click 'Yes I know what I'm doing'.

Click on Import wallet in the left side column.

You can then add the private keys by copying and pasting the output from the command line.